# Getting response from servlet. ExtJs

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, extjs

I have a extJs form with fileupload and servlet. After uploading file i want to get response from servlet.

i do this `System.out.println("{success:true, error:'error'}");`
But in firebug in POST i dont see anything. This code works in case wiht jsp but not servlet. So how to send parametrs from servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out` PrintStream is not the the output stream of your servlet response. It is still the "standard" system out stream. Most application servers redirect that to a log file.

Servlet's `service()` method, as well as `do*()` methods of HttpServlet, take [ServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) respectively [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) as a parameter. When implementing a servlet, one can call `getWriter()` on that parameter to get a `PrintWriter` open on response's output stream. That can be used to print something to the response.

So, your code should be something like:

`response.getWriter().println("{success:true, error:'error'}");`